# How could I delete circles in front of choices in an Android dialog?

Tags: android, dialog

I'm an Android development beginner and I'm trying to create a little app. But I have a little problem that I cannot find the solution to: I want to allow the user to pick a choice in a list so I created an edit text that cannot be written, but when the user clicks on it I open a dialog with all the choices, and when he picks one I modify the edittext.

It works fine but (as on the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZ1BV.png)) when i create a dialog with choices there is circles in front of all the choices. However they are useless because my dialog close immediately after clicking on a choice.
Have you got any idea about how i could delete those useless circles?

Thank you and sorry for my English :)

Comment: Welcome! Your question lacks accompanying code, so it's very difficult to help you with just the description you've provided. You might like to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve which shows how to provide a minimal example that demonstrates your approach. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You are using Switches as Views for your dialog. If you don't want the circles you should use normal TextViews to represent each row.